# Sql Server Count some rows and leave the rest

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I have a select query which results in the table below:

```
RowNo |  ComponentRef | ComponentTitle

  1   |      NULL     |   UsersCount5
  2   |      NULL     |   UsersCount1 
  3   |      NULL     |   UsersCount1
  4   |      NULL     |   UsersCount1
  5   |       2       |   SomeComponent
  6   |       3       |   SomeOtherComponent
  7   |       4       |   YetAnotherComponent
```

I need to have and output like this:

```
RowNo |  ComponentRef | ComponentTitle

  1   |      NULL     |   UsersCount8               ===> (5+1+1+1)
  2   |       2       |   SomeComponent
  3   |       3       |   SomeOtherComponent
  4   |       4       |   YetAnotherComponent
```

I don't know how to count the rows with `ComponentTitle` starting with "UsersCount" and just leave the rest of the rows as they are.

Any help is appreciated.

P.S.1: Forget about the `RowNo` column. I can handle that :)

P.S.2: Instead of `UsersCount8` you could just tell me how to put the `Count` of those specific rows(In this case, `4`). I will handle playing with the string and stuff :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  rowNo, componentRef,
        CASE WHEN componentRef IS NULL THEN 'UsersCount' + ucsum ELSE componentRef END
FROM    (
        SELECT  *,
                SUM(CASE WHEN componentRef IS NULL THEN CAST(REPLACE(componentTitle, 'UsersCount', '') AS INT) END) AS ucsum,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY componentRef ORDER BY rowNum) rn
        ) q
WHERE   componentRef IS NOT NULL OR rn = 1
```

Comment: But I will need a `Group By ComponentTitle` which is making trouble.. Trying to handle that, thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do what you want as:

```
select row_number() over (order by (select NULL)) as seqnum,
       ComponentRef,
       (case when ComponentRef is not null then max(ComponentTitle)
             else cast(count(*) as varchar(255))
        end)
from table t
group by ComponentRef;
```